# Tag cleanup - Part 1 - Results

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, retagging, tagging

These are the current outcomes of [my earlier tag cleanup proposal](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2344/tag-cleanup-part-1-proposal).

Two of our beloved moderators, Elmy and Lila, both helped out with this as well. Thank you to Journeyman Geek for offering feedback (with Elmy) on the initial proposal. Thank you to everyone else who participated or helped.

These excerpts are from my [proposal](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2344/tag-cleanup-part-1-proposal).

---

1. > **Tag creation proposal** - to create a tag [search-and-rescue](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search-and-rescue) (although I am flexible to an alternate tag name).

   - **Results:** Successful! The tag [lost-pets](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lost-pets) (name suggested by Journeyman Geek) has been created.

     - **Details:** It already has 21+ questions! I also gave it an appropriate tag wiki and excerpt.

     *The wiki:*

     > As long as the question includes relevant detail, and is generally focused on "lost pets", this tag should be included. Not to be confused with [strays](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strays). Other related tags include [safety](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/safety), [containment](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/containment), [adoption](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adoption), and [behavior](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behavior).

     *The excerpt:*

     > For questions about finding a lost pet, identifying the owner of a lost pet, questions about lost pets in general, and similar. Not to be confused with the tag "stray".

     - **Additional info:** Please apply this to questions when appropriate. Right now, this tag is completely done, and all that is left is to track down the few related questions and add it (which I encourage anyone to do, regardless of rep, a good search to start with is [this](https://pets.stackexchange.com/search?q=lost%20pet)) as well as remembering to add it to new questions.
2. > **Tag burnination** - to [burninate](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2344/tag-cleanup-part-1-proposal) the tag [community-faq](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-faq).

   - **Results:** Idea rejected.

     - **Details:** Turns out this is a legit tag that is an exception to the "meta tag" rule, so it should be kept. In fact, we need to add questions to it, but that is a project for another day (maybe after summer I will take on this).
3. > **Tag edits/possible renames** -  [shelter](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shelter) vs [rescue-organizations](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rescue-organizations).

   - **Results:** Successful! Thanks to Elmy, these tags have been combined.

     - **Details:** [rescue-organizations](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rescue-organizations) is now a synonym of [shelter](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shelter). Tag [shelter](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shelter) also got a wiki and excerpt.

     *The wiki:*

     > For questions about the process of adopting pets from a shelter or animal rescue organization and about any problem that might arise in the context of such an adoption. With "shelter" we mean any establishment that temporarily takes ownership for pets, regardless of whether it's maintained by private organizations, local government, or supported by charitable contributions,

     *The excerpt:*

     > Any establishment that provides a temporary home for dogs, cats, and other animals that are offered for adoption.

     - **Additional info:** Please apply this to questions when appropriate. Right now, this tag is completely done, and all that is left is to track down the *many* related questions and add it (which I encourage anyone and everyone to do, regardless of rep, a good search to start with is [this](https://pets.stackexchange.com/search?q=shelter), remember not questions about pets that were shelter animals, questions directly related to shelters and rescue organizations) as well as remembering to add it to new questions.
4. > - tag [clothes](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clothes) should be made synonyms with [attire](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/attire). And [attire](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/attire) should have the "collar" part in its description removed because of tag [leashes](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leashes) includes collars. Also [collar](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/collar) should be made synonyms with [leashes](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leashes). To clarify, there would be two separate tags out of this bunch, [attire](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/attire) would be one, which would include [clothes](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clothes) and then [leashes](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leashes) would now include [collar](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/collar) and it would be made separate from [attire](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/attire).

   - **Results:** Successful, but slightly tweaked!

     - **Details:** In the end, I just removed [clothes](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clothes). It is not a synonym as there were so few questions tagged with it. However, I did get the "collar" part in its description removed. See this change to [attire](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/attire) [here](https://pets.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/25405) and [here](https://pets.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/25404). Due to feedback, I decided to create a new tag, [collar](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/collar), instead of merging its scope with [leashes](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leashes). I also updated [leashes](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leashes) wiki and excerpt, view these changes [here](https://pets.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/25423) and [here](https://pets.stackexchange.com/posts/31542/revisions). Finally, I gave [collar](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/collar) a wiki and excerpt:

     *The wiki:*

     > For questions about the band/ring used around a pet's neck (typically a dog, but can be used for other pets too) to restrain, decorate, control, or protect.
     >
     > Relevant tags include [leashes](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leashes), [leash-training](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leash-training), [training](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/training), and [behavior](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behavior).

     *The excerpt:*

     > The band/ring used around a pet's neck (typically a dog, but can be used for other pets too) to restrain, decorate, control, or protect.

     - **Additional info:** Please add [leashes](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leashes), [attire](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/attire) and [collar](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/collar) to questions when appropriate. Right now, these tags are almost done. We have to track down the *many* related questions and add the appropriate tags (which I beg anyone and everyone to do, regardless of rep, a good search to start with could be "collar", "leashes", "clothes", or "costumes".) Because [collar](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/collar) is a new and incomplete tag, there are at least 30 relevant questions that can use it.
5. > - the tags [horse](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horse), [goats](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/goats), [cows](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cows), [sheep](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sheep) and [pig](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pig) (and similar) should be synonyms of [farm-animals](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/farm-animals) or, if we want separate farm animal tags, the tag [farm-animals](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/farm-animals) should be destroyed.

   - **Results:** Due to lack of opinion and some confusion, I have decided not to do anything about this. Feel free to figure this out yourself... but for now, most likely this topic will be dormant.
6. > - tags [showing](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/showing), [competitions](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/competitions), and possibly [showmanship](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/showmanship) should be merged into one.

   - **Results:** Successful! Tag [competitions](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/competitions) is now the head tag.

     - **Details:** I combined [showing](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/showing), [competitions](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/competitions), [showmanship](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/showmanship), and an added [conformation-show](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conformation-show) into [competitions](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/competitions). I also gave tag [competitions](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/competitions) a wiki and excerpt.

   *The wiki:*

   > For questions about any type of competition for pets, such as animal racing or dog shows. Please use for anything directly related to competitions, showings, showmanship, conformation shows, and similar. Related tags include  [training](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/training), [pet-selection](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pet-selection), and [agility](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/agility). Also use the breed participating in the competition's tag as well (e.g. [dogs](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dogs)).

   *The excerpt:*

   > Any type of competition for pets, such as animal racing or dog shows. Please use for anything directly related to competitions, showings, showmanship, conformation shows, and similar.

   - **Additional info:** Please add any relevant questions to [competitions](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/competitions), although it is a lesser-used topic so this won't be hard. Other than that, this tag is fully complete!

---

That is the end of Part 1. Again thank you, and please work with me to edit the newly added or forgotten tags into questions. Participation in this tag-editing work can be tedious, but it will pay off!

Anyhow... thanks again. Expect a Part 2 in the fall.

If you have feedback for this process or the results, I'd love to hear it as an answer to this announcement.

Bye!

Comment: Thanks for your hard work! The [tag:farm-animals] tag might be problematic because it sits squarely in the grey area between on-topic and off-topic. We exclude husbandry from our scope, but [a single chicken isn't husbandry](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/31347/12501), we have many questions about horses, people can form a very [close relationship with pigs](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/27226/12501) and [goats don't only live on farms](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/21334/12501).

Comment: @Elmy Please consider upv∗ting the question if it is helpful thanks.

Comment: @Nai45 Please consider upv∗ting my comment if it was helpful, thanks.

Comment: @lila Please consider upv*ting this comment if it was helpful ;)

Comment: @Nai45 Please consider starring [this chat message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58447569#58447569) if it is helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Big thanks for all your initiative and effort; I am personally almost completely illiterate in the subject of tags, and for me the work needed to do this seems as fascinating as sitting in the armchair and watching chips of plaster falling off from the old walls all day long. All I know about tags is intuitive feeling which ones fit which questions.

Retagging cleanup event did not earn you any significant amounts of reputation and I assume it was intensely mundane and repetitive, and thus I think we should all appreciate your efforts even more.

### How to properly express your gratitude for Nai45's efforts

Please turn off all the lights in your room, light up 7 candles and 7 incense sticks, start quietly chanting, bow 7 times in the direction of printed picture of Nai45's avatar that is hanging there on your wall, and slowly start entering meditation state. Sit there and soak up the atmosphere while observing the burning candles and smoldering incense sticks; once either the first candle or the first incense stick is burnt out, stand up while increasing the volume of your chanting and use your mouse device to upvote the Nai45's question in this Q&A; once you are done, use the light switch to turn off all the candles that are still lit, and log out of Pets SE. Thanks for cooperation.

Comment: I love this. Thanks :D